# S3 VPC endpoint IAM breaks the access to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using S3 VPC endpoint (type: gateway). I've wanted to restrict access to S3 resources from my private subnet only to my resources that belong to my account. I've used below IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [       
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalAccount": ["myAccountId"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this works fine for S3, however it breaks the access to ECR from the node itself, so it no longer can pull the docker images.

This is what happens when I use `docker pull`:

```
error pulling image configuration: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<Error>...Access Denied...</Error>"
```

This is the message from the Kubernetes node that tries to fetch the image:

```
Failed to pull image "<accountId>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<repoName>:<tag>": failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://<accountId>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/<repoName/blobs/sha256:<hash>: 403 Forbidden
```

If I remove the principal account condition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [       
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"       
        }
    ]
}
```

things are working OK.

It seem to me that ECR endpoint creates pre-signed URL to S3, which then gets blocked by my above policy.

Is there any way to allow ECR pre-signed URL, whilst still restricting access to only AWS resources that belong to my account?

Comment: Maybe create an independent process that pulls images from ECR periodically and makes them available to your app via the VPC endpoint-enabled S3 bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After displaying Docker daemon logs I've noticed that it tries to fetch the resource from: `prod-eu-west1-starport-layer-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

I've then found AWS specific documentation which describes minimal permissions required:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html#ecr-setting-up-s3-gateway

I've then added this block to my S3 VPC endpoint IAM:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-eu-west-1-starport-layer-bucket/*"
}
```

and things started to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. We had the exact same problem and couldn't find a solution for almost the entire day until finding your answer.